# How to change the Visible Property of an image using a button in MFC application (C++ Visual Studio 2010)?

Tags: c++, mfc, picturebox, visible

I am trying to make a program where an image would disappear when a certain a button called hide in the application is pressed.

I  know in Windows form application it would be something like this:

```
    pictureBox1->Visible=true/false;
```

But that code wouldn't work in MFC

My code in MFC is

```
     Cstatic pictureBox1 =(Cstatic)Getdialogitem(IDC_IMAGE1);
     pictureBox1->Visible=false;
```

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
pictureBox1->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
```

or

```
pictureBox1->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
```

In MFC, simply setting a member variable to a new value doesn't accomplish anything; you need to call functions that will take specific actions.